# Why i can't get the object inside object?

Tags: php

i have $thisobject..

```
object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "test1"
  }
  ["2"]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test2"
  }
  ["3"]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test3"
  }
  ["4"]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "test4"
  }
}
```

why `var_dump($thisobject->1)` does not print the object inside?

it returns this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\dev\project\www\test.php on line 15

Comment: It's not like github with the 3x ` :)

Comment: ahh, sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax to access object inside would be:

```
$thisobject->{'1'}
```